# Rollup function is not working in riemman when clj-time.core is added

Tags: clojure, riemann

I am using riemann to trigger an email alert which should get triggered only during 3AM to 8PM daily. When I have added clj-time.core function rollup function is not working.

Don't know where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
(tcp-server {:host "127.0.0.1" :port 5555})

(let [userindex1 (default :ttl 300 (update-index (index)))])  
  (let [email (mailer {....email configuration})]
            (streams
        (where (service "log")
            (smap
              (fn [events]
               (let [count-of-transaction (count (filter #(= "error" (:type %)) events))]
                  (event
                  {
                     :status "Failure"
                     :metric  count-of-failures 
                     :total-fail (< count-of-failures 2)})))

              (where (let [now (clj-time.core/now)]
                    (and (<= 3 (clj-time.core/hour now) 20)
                         (= (:status event) "Failure")
                         (:total-fail event)))
                (rollup 1 200
                (email "xxx@xx.com")
                 ))prn))))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's not working? What's the error message?

Comment: It doesn't throw any error message but whenever the condition get satisfied it triggering the email when I added this code `(let [now (clj-time.core/now)]
                    (and (<= 3 (clj-time.core/hour now) 20)`my `rollup; function is not working properly. If I remove the above mentioned code my `rollup` function triggers properly and it sents an email at every `200 sec` interval